# Pyspark: Error Connecting to Snowflake using Private Key

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, etl, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking to create an ETL process that reads queries from Snowflake. Most of the examples online show how to set up a connection using a regular string password, but the way my company has set up their password is via private key. Unfortunately, when I try to pass in the private key as a parameter, it returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rihun/PycharmProjects/snowflake_gcp_etl/loader.py", line 61, in <module>
    .option("query", query) \
  File "/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 172, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load())
  File "/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 79, in deco
    raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: 'Input PEM private key is invalid'
```

**Code Example:**

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark
import os

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.6.24,net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.11:2.4.12-spark_2.3 pyspark-shell'

from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from snowflake_connector import get_keeper_token, get_snowflake_credentials

spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local').appName('Snowflake Loader').config('spark.driver.memory', '5G').getOrCreate()

spark.builder.config('spark.executor.memory', '16G')
spark.builder.config('spark.executor.cores', '4')

SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME = "net.snowflake.spark.snowflake"

sf_creds = get_snowflake_credentials(keeper_token=get_keeper_token())

sfOptions = {
    "sfURL": sf_creds['sfURL'],
    "sfAccount": sf_creds['sfAccount'],
    "sfUser": sf_creds['sfUser'],
    "pem_private_key": sf_creds['sfPrivateKey'],
    "sfDatabase": sf_creds['sfDatabase'],
    "sfSchema": sf_creds['sfSchema'],
    "sfWarehouse": sf_creds['sfWarehouse'],
}

df = spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME) \
    .options(**sfOptions) \
    .option("query", query) \
    .load()

df.count()
```

**How I am getting the credentials**

```
def get_snowflake_credentials(keeper_token: str,
                         keeper_url='<keeper_url>',
                         keeper_namespace='cloudDB',
                         keeper_secret_path='<path_to_key>',
                         sf_account='<sf_account>',
                         sf_svc_user='<user>',
                         sf_wh='<warehouse>',
                         sf_role='<role>',
                         sf_db='<db>',
                         sf_schema='<schema>'):
    # Connect to Keeper to collect secrets
    client = hvac.Client(
        url=keeper_url,
        namespace=keeper_namespace,
        token=keeper_token
    )

    # Secrets are stored within the key entitled 'data'
    keeper_secrets = client.read(keeper_secret_path)['data']
    passphrase = keeper_secrets['SNOWSQL_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE']
    private_key = keeper_secrets['private_key']

    # PEM key must be byte encoded
    key = bytes(private_key, 'utf-8')

    p_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
        key
        , password=passphrase.encode()
        , backend=default_backend()
    )

    pkb = p_key.private_bytes(
        encoding=serialization.Encoding.DER
        , format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8
        , encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption())

    sf_client = snowflake.connector.connect(
        user=sf_svc_user
        , account=sf_account
        , warehouse=sf_wh
        , role=sf_role
        , database=sf_db
        , schema=sf_schema
        , private_key=pkb)

    return {
        "sfURL": "<url>",
        "sfAccount": sf_account,
        "sfUser": sf_svc_user,
        "sfPrivateKey": pkb,
        "sfDatabase": sf_db,
        "sfSchema": sf_schema,
        "sfWarehouse": sf_wh
    }
```

Comment: Try upgrading the JDBC connector and see if that helps. I saw this issue a while back with an older connector and upgrading helped in that case (net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.8.0,net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.11:2.4.14-spark_2.4).  You could also try testing with Python just to see if the issue is specific to Spark.

Comment: Thanks Suzy - I tried connecting with Python, and it seemed to work just fine. So I think this issue is a spark specific problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, upgrading the JDBC connector didn't seem to resolve the issue

Comment: That's interesting that it works with Python.  Can you upgrade Spark at all? Might be worth a Support ticket if you can't get it to work.

Comment: I created an issue on their GitHub issues.

Answer (score 2):

```
Can you try with this code.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    #!/usr/bin/env python
    # coding=utf-8
    from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
    from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
    from pyspark.sql.types import *
    from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
    from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
    from pyspark.sql.types import *
    from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
    import subprocess
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    import os
    import logging
    from logging import getLogger
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
    import re
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_pem_private_key

    v_log = '<path>/spark.log'

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .config("spark.jars", "<path>/snowflake-jdbc-3.8.0.jar,<path>/spark-snowflake_2.11-2.4.13-spark_2.4.jar") \
    .config("spark.repl.local.jars",
            "<path>/snowflake-jdbc-3.8.0.jar,<path>/spark-snowflake_2.11-2.4.13-spark_2.4.jar") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalogImplementation", "in-memory") \
    .getOrCreate()

spark._jvm.net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeConnectorUtils.enablePushdownSession(
    spark._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate())   

    logging.basicConfig(
            filename=v_log,
            level=logging.DEBUG)
    logger = getLogger(__name__)



    with open("<path-to>/rsa_key.p8", "rb") as key_file:
        p_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
            key_file.read(),
            password=os.environ['PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE'].encode(),
            backend=default_backend()
        )

    pkb = p_key.private_bytes(
        encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
        format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
        encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption()
    )
    pkb = pkb.decode("UTF-8")
    pkb = re.sub("-*(BEGIN|END) PRIVATE KEY-*\n", "", pkb).replace("\n", "")


    sfOptions = {
        "sfURL": "<URL>",
        "sfAccount": "sfcsupport",
        "sfUser": "",
        "sfDatabase": "",
        "sfSchema": "PUBLIC",
        "sfWarehouse": "",
        "sfRole": "",
        "pem_private_key":pkb
    }




    SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME = "net.snowflake.spark.snowflake"

    df = spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME) \
        .options(**sfOptions) \
        .option("query", "Select * from <TableName>") \
        .load()


    df.show()

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks Ankur! Do I run the code as is? I'm getting an error - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: net.snowflake.spark.snowflake. Please find packages at

Comment: Updated it .Please try with this one and make changes accordingly.

Comment: May I also ask what spark version and python version you are using? I'm using Spark 2.3.3 and Python 3.7

Comment: I am using Python 3.7 and Spark 2.4.3.In this code i am loading in memory jars and below 2 lines are the key :                                                                            
 pkb = pkb.decode("UTF-8")
 pkb = re.sub("-*(BEGIN|END) PRIVATE KEY-*\n", "", pkb).replace("\n", "")

Comment: Just got a chance to try this out, and I'm getting the following error: JDBC driver not able to connect to Snowflake. Error code: 390100, Message: Incorrect username or password was specified.

I can confirm that I'm using the correct credentials as well. Maybe the jars files I'm using are the incorrect version?